Using AzureDefaultCredentials in Powershell
We are currently looking to use Powershell to run some automated test scripts in our Azure environments and seem to be hitting a stumbling block. There does not seem to be a way of using AzureDefaultCredentials, and the only option we can find is to use username and password.
We found the following resource (and similar ones)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials?tabs=azure-powershell
But they all seems to indicate that you

Create an automation user
Create credentials
Set username and password
Turn off MFA
Add the username and password in the script (potentially via secrets, making it a bit safer)

So it would look something like:
$myCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'MyCredential'
$userName = $myCredential.UserName
$securePassword = $myCredential.Password
$password = $myCredential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

When we do the same in .net and python, we will instead use the DefaultCredentials, so on the local machine, you log in with az login, and the script will use those, and in the VM in the function app, the VM will get its credentials from the System Assigned Identity.
So all we do is
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

But there does not seem to be such functionality in PowerShell where we don't need to use username and password, or are we just looking in the wrong place

Get default credentials using $myCredential =  Get-Credential


Using AzureDefaultCredentials in PowerShell:

To login into Azure using PowerShell non interactively, you can use managed identity authentication, or a service principal authentication with PowerShell command as detailed in the MS Doc.
Refer Non interactive authentication into Azure using PowerShell.

Service Principal:

$appid="xxxxx"
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName $appid
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant "xxxx"



Managed Identity:

connect-AzAccount -identity


Note: The above two authentication approaches work in the same way as a Default Azure credential way.
And you can also use Get-Credential PowerShell command to directly store and retrieve the username and password. Once its stored, pass the credentials along with the Connect-AzAccount -credential argument as suggested by @jdweng as well.

